# How to capture search results count in selenium java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How to capture search result count.It varies each time I had tried with
`int result = driver.findelements(by.xpath("")).size();` but always I'm getting 0. XPath is correct.

Code in website:

```
<div class="search-msg-count ng-binding">Search result count: 100 entries</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Capture the text from the Element with the xpath -

```
WebElement e = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='search-msg-count ng-binding']"));
String elementText = e.getText().trim();
```

Then split the string with ":"  -

```
String split[] = elementText.split(":");
```

Your required text will be in second array element. Get it & replace entries word from it.

```
String finalValue = split[1].replace("entries","").trim();
System.out.println(finalValue);
```